# My java program doesn't display special characters on another devices

Tags: java, encoding, ansi-escape

I wrote a program that reads from a file has Arabic text encoded with ANSI.
I made a runnable jar of that program.
It run perfectly on my Laptop, however, when I run it on another laptop the Arabic characters turn into a messy symbols.
So what to do?

Comment: A runnable jar and the Android tag don't make sense. In any case, please show screeenshots and a [mcve]

Comment: You should only use the Unicodes which are accepted gloablly Refer this [site](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/0600-06FF) for uniocdes of Arabic. The other device showing messy symbols because it tries to read un supported unicode characters

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure your end system is having the fonts required to display those letters if not bundle it with your application.
2. Check whether you are reading the file content UTF-8 (Or appropriate encoding format).